# Why is My plotly plot not displaying? I've tried show(), I've tried calling it manually, still no use?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, figure

So, this is the code, and for some reason, nothing shows up when I call fig? just a blank line, tried it with plot(),show(), still no use.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.offline import iplot

df = pd.read_csv('covid_19_data.csv')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(8,8)})
sns.heatmap(df.isnull(),yticklabels=False)

df['ObservationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ObservationDate'],format='%m/%d/%Y',utc=True)

df_grp = df.groupby('ObservationDate').agg({'Confirmed':'sum','Deaths':'sum','Recovered':'sum'})
df_grp['Active'] = df_grp['Confirmed'] -df_grp['Deaths'] - df_grp['Recovered']
df_grp = df_grp.reset_index()

fig = px.bar(df_grp,x ='ObservationDate',y = 'Confirmed',color_discrete_sequence=['red'])
```

[this is the pic of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH2GJ.jpg) It doesn't come in the plot section as well.

Here for download is the data set under covid_19_data
https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/novel-corona-virus-2019-dataset

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please post a sample of your data? It would greatly increase the probability of someone posting an answer.

Comment: Your code fully works in my environment.  Only addition `fig` or `fig.show()` to display Plotly graph.  I'm using JupyterLab and using Plotly plugin https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes, Sure will add the entire data

Comment: @RobRaymond I tried using fig, but it didn't work. and I did use the same version of plotly ,so now Idea why it doesn't work. Any idea? I've put in the image of what happens in the chat as well.

Comment: recently I experienced a similar issue.  I completely tore down (deleted) my venv including jupyter and rebuilt from re-install. There was an issue between plotly version and jupyterlab plugin.  it had been 6 months since I had used plotly